# online, background image not being shown on full page

Tags: css

online linked image to full body, not being shown on webpage. Although, the local image are being shown.

inspected developers tools, there was no error except,

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked a cross-origin response,
> "black-horse-running-on-green-field-surrounded-with-trees-101667/"

Image is not being loaded, screen is white. Expecting solution?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-image: url('https://www.pexels.com/photo/black-horse-running-on-green-field-surrounded-with-trees-101667/');
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Welcome to Our Website</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut dicta consequatur quidem incidunt officia tempora.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Find Out More</a>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: I suggest you read about [CORB](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers/), it's the reason that your image isn't loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong link.
You're using the link that goes to the web page. You need the link with only the image.

To get this link, right-click on the image and copy the image link.

Here's what you can put in your code:

```
 header {
     background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/101667/pexels-photo-101667.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2');
          color:#fff;
          height:100vh;
          background-size: cover;
          background-position: center;
     }
```